# Cambiar de INT a CHAR para hacer una consulta de comparación

Tags: java

Este es mi código. Lo uso para llamar números iguales a ese ejemplo *12345*

```
int fechapagos = Integer.parseInt(efecha.getText().toString());
```

Pero necesito ahora llamar fechas iguales a ejemplo *12/02/2023*

Intento cambiar a `char` pero el `Integer.parseInt` me da error.

```
char fechapagos = Integer.parseInt(efecha.getText().toString());
```

¿Qué debo hacer o reemplazar?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` da un `Integer`, no un `int`. No hay cast implícito ahí. En vez de hacer cast a Integer, simplemente recibe el String (que no es un char, porque un char es de UN carácter) y lo usas en tu consulta. Como no hay más código, no hay más que podamos sugerir

Comment: osea que no deberia usar char sino String en lugar de char y quitar el integer? listo muchas gracias lo are

Comment: puedes pasar la cadena con un objeto dateformat a el api de manejo de fechas de tu preferencia y usar la comparacion que te trae por defecto dicho api, en el caso de que seas vieja escuela y uses date, estos objetos internamente tienen la representacion en milisegundos y la comparacion por ello es relativamente rapida

Answer (score 0):

el tipo `char`, almacena un único valor, osea esto es válido:

```
char a = 'a';
```

esto no es válido:

```
char ab = 'ab';
```

Como te darás cuenta, intentar almacenar "***12/02/2023***" como `char`, siempre te va a arrojar un error.
Por otro lado, `Integer.parseInt()` te devuelve un `int`... siempre y cuando tenga una entrada adecuada, por lo que es correcto:

```
int fa = Integer.parseInt( "714" );
```

No es correcto:

```
int sol = Integer.parseInt( "7/14" );
```

Otro desliz, sería la siguiente linea:

```
efecha.getText().toString()
```

Sin importar el tipo de **`efecha`**, le estoy pidiendo que me de el texto que contiene... lo que deja sin sentido el **`toString()`** (aunque no rompe, es innecesario).
En cuanto al manejo de la fecha, te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
LocalDate fechapagos = LocalDate.parse( "2023-02-12" );
```

O si quieres usar el formato "`dd/MM/yyy`"

```
DateTimeFormatter frmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
LocalDate salida;
try {
   salida = LocalDate.parse( fecha, frmt );
}
catch( Exception e ) {  
   salida = LocalDate.parse( "1999-01-01" );
}
```

Puedes encontrar más info sobre `LocalDate` [aquí](https://quejava.com/java-localdate/).

Comment: muchas gracias ire aplicarlo porque con string como me mencionaron no me funciono o no se como hacerlo funcionar pero ya con esta explicacion, puede que si lo haga muchas gracias ire aplicarlo

Comment: Un placer maestro!.

Comment: si funciono con String